# PCI Compliance Network Scan Issue - HTTP response code was an expected 401

Tags: pci-dss

We take Credit card over internet connected comupter, and we have to pass PCI compliance network scan. When I run network scan , I have the following error. How can i fix this error.
Any help appreciated.

Running vulnerable HTTP service.
HTTP request to

```
http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/
```

HTTP response code was an expected
401

```
1: Basic realm="WEB Remote
Viewer"
```

Comment: What has your research revealed?

Answer (score 5):

The PCI DSS requires that passwords are not transmitted in the clear. Basic auth over HTTP would result in clear-text transmission of the password.

Enable SSL for port 8080.